# change login behaviour in FOSUserBundle & LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.3, lexikjwtauthbundle, api-platform.com

I'm using [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) with [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) to access data from and API.

The users login with username & password. A token is generated and then is used in every request as credentials.

Is it possible to use another field to perform a login?

Let's say I have another attribute in my entity, *authCode*, how can I tell these bundles to login via username & authCode or maybe username & password & authCode?

Comment: Yes it is possible - for example with a custom **guard authenticator**.

Comment: @nifr That looks promising, thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes if you provide `authCode` during registration and it belongs to the user entity 
in security.yml

```
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.authCode
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make login with authCode and password? I still need to use username